# 2-transitive permutation groups of small degree

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, gap

I've recently been learning about 2-transitive permutation groups. To better my understanding of the classification of 2-transitive groups I'm trying to learn about 2-transitive permutation groups of small degree, say $ n \leq 30 $. To make this slightly more manageable I've confined myself to odd degree.

Is this the full list of 2-transitive permutation groups for odd degree $ n \leq 30 $ (excluding $ A_n,S_n $)? $ n $ is the degree $ k $ is the transitivity

| $n$ | $k$ | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | $AGL(1,5)$ |
| 7 | 2 | $AGL(1,7)$ |
| 7 | 2 | $PSL(3,2)$ |
| 9 | 2 | $AGL(1,9)=3^2:8$ |
| 9 | 2 | $AGL(2,3)=3^2:2S_4$ |
| 9 | 2 | $ASL(2,3)=3^2:2A_4$ |
| 9 | 2 | $3^2:Q_8$ |
| 9 | 2 | $3^2:2D_8$ |
| 9 | 3 | $PSL(2,8)$ |
| 9 | 3 | $P\Gamma L(2,8)$ |
| 11 | 2 | $AGL(1,11)$ |
| 11 | 2 | $PSL(2,11)$ |
| 11 | 4 | $M_{11}$ |
| 13 | 2 | $AGL(1,13)$ |
| 13 | 2 | $PSL(3,3)$ |
| 15 | 2 | $PSL(4,2)\cong A_8$ |
| 15 | 2 | $A_7$ |
| 17 | 2 | $AGL(1,17)$ |
| 17 | 3 | $PSL(2,16)\leq G \leq P\Gamma L(2,16)$ (3 total) |
| 19 | 2 | $AGL(1,19)$ |
| 21 | 2 | $PSL(3,4)\leq G \leq P\Gamma L(3,4)$(4 total) |
| 23 | 2 | $AGL(1,23)$ |
| 23 | 4 | $M_{23}$ |
| 25 | 2 | $ASL(2,5)\leq G \leq A \Gamma L(2,5)$ (7 total) |
| 25 | 2 | $AGL(1,25)$ |
| 25 | 2 | $A\Gamma L(1,25)$ |
| 27 | 2 | $AGL(3,3)$ |
| 27 | 2 | $ASL(3,3)$ |
| 27 | 2 | $AGL(1,27)$ |
| 27 | 2 | $A\Gamma L(1,27)$ |
| 29 | 2 | $AGL(1,29)$ |

Edit: I updated the list using the answer/comments/GAP code from comments

Edit 2: reader beware I think I fixed the degree 27 groups but seems like my degree 25 groups still aren't right

Comment: You could check this yourself very easily using GAP. I can see immediately that you are missing ${\rm P \Gamma L}(2,8)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt That would definitely be even better! Is there a GAP command to see if a group is 2 transitive? I would love to know how to check this all myself in GAP. And  $ P\Gamma L(2,8) $ would be for  $ n=9 $ I guess? Its an almost simple group that is the  automorphism group of $ PSL(2,8) $ or something like that?

Comment: `AllTransitiveGroups(NrMovedPoints,[5..30],Transitivity,[2,3]);` will give you 2 and 3-transitive groups e.g.

Comment: @ahulpke Of course that misses out $M_{11}$ and $M_{23}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt that's true! But I just used AllTransitiveGroups(NrMovedPoints,[5..30],Transitivity,[2,3,4,5]); instead to be extra careful when I checked all this stuff in GAP. Although then you also get $ A_5,S_5 $ in degree $ 5 $, and $ A_7 $ in degree $ 7 $ which are kind of trivial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these are not all. You are missing:

- Subgroups of $AGL(k,p)$ that contain the full $p^k$, and are semidirect product with a transitive complement (e.g. a Singer Cycle, or automorphism of the SL): $3^2:Q_8$, $3^2:2D_8$, $AGL(2,3)$.
  Groups containing $PSL(2,16)$, but with Galois automorphisms on top.
  8 in degree 25 (amongst them $ASL(2,5):2$ and $AGL(2,5)$, $AGL(1,25)$, $A\Gamma L(1,25)$, in Degree 27 $AGL(3,3)$ and $A\Gamma L(1,27)$.

(The groups $\Gamma L$ arise by taking Galois automorphisms of SL in addition to GL.)

- $PSL(3,4)$ (and 3 supergroups) in degree $21=\frac{4^3-1}{4-1}$.

Comment: I edited my list I think now everything should pretty much be right. E(9) in GAP just means elementary abelian $ p $ group with 9 elements, right? Am I right that $ AGL(1,9)=3^2:8 $? That seems a bit odd since I think of $ AGL(1,9) = C_9 \rtimes C_8 $ as a semidirect product of cyclic groups.

Comment: AGL(1,9) takes the *field* with 9 elements, which additively is a $3\times 3$.

Comment: In your edit, in deg 25, not all contain ASL(2,5). You for example get 5^2:24 with the 24 a Singer cycle.

Comment: For the missing groups in degrees n=25, 27, take the field $F$ with $n$ elements and consider the semidirect product $F\rtimes F^*$, acting on the elements of $F$. It is doubly transitive since all nonzero elements of $F$ have a multiplicative inverse, and it lies in $AGL(k,p)$ for $n=p^k$.

Comment: Just to be clear, $ A:B $ means the a split extension $ A \rtimes B $, right? Or does $ : $ just mean any extension?

Comment: Yes (ATLAS notation). Colon is split, period is undefined (couls be either). Middle dot is explicitly nonsplit.